# Json Schema validation: should raise Exception when there are unrecognized fields

Tags: python, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

A simple example:

```
import json
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "description" : {"type" : "string"},
        "value_c" : { "type": "object", 
                      "properties": {"x": { "type": "string" }, 
                                     "z": { "type": "string" }}, 
                      "required": ["x"], 
                      "maxProperties": 2}
    },
    "required": ["description", "value_c"]
}

my_json = json.loads('{"description": "Hello world!", "value_c": {"x": "5", "z222": "6" } }')

validate(instance=my_json, schema=schema)
```

*There is no Exception raised* after executing this code snippet. But **I would like to raise an Exception when there are new unrecognized fields**: in this case: `z222`.

Not sure if the Python library `jsonschema` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/)) supports this feature? If no, please feel free to suggest alternatives. If yes, I think we need to change the schema definition somehow...

#### Environment

- Python 3.10.6 (64 bit)

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but you could try to use [additionalProperties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties): false instead of maxProperties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to @Uli Sotschok

Using [Additional Properties](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties) solves my issue: raise Exception when there are new unrecognized fields.

Full example:

```
import json
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "description" : {"type" : "string"},
        "value_c" : { "type": "object", 
                      "properties": {"x": { "type": "string" }, 
                                     "z": { "type": "string" }}, 
                      "required": ["x"], 
                      "additionalProperties": False}
    },
    "required": ["description", "value_c"]
}

my_json = json.loads('{"description": "Hello world!", "value_c": {"x": "5", "z222": "6" } }')

validate(instance=my_json, schema=schema)
```

The Exception:

```
ValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed ('z222' was unexpected)

Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema['properties']['value_c']:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'x': {'type': 'string'}, 'z': {'type': 'string'}},
     'required': ['x'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance['value_c']:
    {'x': '5', 'z222': '6'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try pydantic

```
from pydantic import *

class Test(BaseModel):
    description: str = None
    value_c: str = None
    
    
    class Config:
       allow_population_by_field_name = True
       extra = Extra.forbid


    data = {
    "description": "This is. test descriptiion",
    "value_c": "This is test value c",
    "value_d": " Test extra field"
}

test_instance = Test(**data)
```

If you run the code, you will get a validation error, if you want to allow an extra field then in the config class set the extra variable as followings. By default, the extra field will be ignored.

> extra= Extra.allow